# SQLite file in project catalogue, use fmdb open it failed

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

I create a table in `SQLite Manager` and export it to desktop , its name is `db_fo_dic.sqlite`, and I can open the `db_fo_dic.sqlite` use `SQLite Manager`, so I copy the `db_fo_dic.sqlite` to my Xcode project catalogue, I try to open the sqlite file by `FMDB`, but it failed:

`NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"db_fo_dic" ofType:@"sqlite"];`

`FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];`

The result info is :
`2016-08-01 19:22:34.955 test_sqlite[15380:425242] The FMDatabase <FMDatabase: 0x7ff589c38f10> is not open.`

This is the location path of my sqlite:
`/Users/youpude/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/87D0245A-47F7-4741-81B2-209625CB3C5E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/47B3AD1F-C08E-4E34-8858-494A95FB9EA5/test_sqlite.app/db_fo_dic.sqlite`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8 hours go through, I find the method to solve my problem finally.

```
#import "FMDatabaseQueue.h"

static FMDatabaseQueue *_queue;
```

in `- (void)viewDidLoad`:

`_queue = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:path];`

and I can query my database:

```
[_queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {

        FMResultSet *result = [db executeQuery:@"select * from dic_content limit 10;"];

        while ([result next]) {

            NSString *str = [result stringForColumn:@"tit"];

            NSLog(@"%@",str);
        }

    }];
```

I use this method to replace the previous method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have write permission for content stored in app bundle. So you have to first copy your database to document directory. For more details about permissions of file system in iOS refer [Apple documentation for file system](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html).

So you can do something like,

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    self.documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    self.databaseFilename = dbFilename;

 NSString* destinationPath = [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath]) {
    NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];
    NSError *error;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destinationPath error:&error];

    if (error != nil) {

        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }

}
```

here `dbFilename` is your database's name (in your case : `db_fo_dic.sqlite`).

After doing this, try to open database from destination path and it will work i think!

Comment: I tested copy my sqlite to sandbox before your answer，it did not work for me.

Comment: try to get path like `NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db_fo_dic.sqlite"];` and then try